# netplan: how to run script on if-up of specified device only

Tags: server, netplan

When I use ifupdown, I wrote a script in if-up.d and use $IFACE to detect the name of the device affected.

Now I turn to netplan in Ubuntu Server 18.04. 2 questions need to be solved:

1 Where to put the command to run the script?
https://netplan.io/faq says there should be placed in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/50-ifup-hooks. Only this file name is allowed? Actually, no such a directory in my instance at all.

2 How to detect the affected device name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in `/usr/share/doc/networkd-dispatcher/README.md.gz`, the device name is passed in the `IFACE` environment variable, the same as is used for if-up.d.

This document also describes the naming requirements of network-dispatcher hook scripts.

Please note that as of Ubuntu 18.04, networkd-dispatcher only supports reading its hooks from `/usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher`, not from `/etc/networkd-dispatcher`.  (This is a bug in the netplan.io website; but the correct fix is for the package to gain support for `/etc/networkd-dispatcher`.)